# exe can't be run in dos mode

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I am programming in C for a hobby project and I want to run it in DOSbox. I have a 64 bit system and I am using gcc to compile.

I am using `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h`, `string.h`

When running the `.exe` I get the error ***"This program cannot be run in DOS mode".*** I have looked around a bit and it said that I need to use some specific libraries to maintain cross-platform, so what should I keep or not keep? I am pretty new to c, should I be using batch files or something else?

Comment: You need to compile it with a compiler for that platform. Now you’ve compiled it for Windows, so get a gcc that targets DOS.

Answer (score 1):

DOS is not Windows.

There are several windows specific libraries and APIs which are not supported by DOS. As a result a executable compiled for Windows won't work with DOS.

You need to tell your compiler that you want to compile *for* DOS. This can be done on Windows too. It is called cross compiling.
The only compiler that I know (which is still available) that can target DOS is Borland C compiler (BCC).
BCC is available for both Windows and Linux.

The Borland C compiler is also used by TurboC compiler.
There are versions of Turbo C which work well with DOSbox (since that is what you are using).

Having said that, unless there is a strong constraint that forces you to compile for DOS (like school/college restrictions or you have to develop for some very old system), I would suggest you move towards newer and better compilers that target Windows.